# AzureML RunDetails widget output

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

In the `RunDetails` Jupyter module, what does the table (see screenshot below) represent?

[image: Azure ML RunDetails Widget]

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! There's many people willing to help, but can you please write a paragraph that describes your question and include the picture inline (instead of as a link)?

Comment: I made an edit that shows what most users are looking for.

Comment: @AndersSwanson Thanks a lot. Actually, I didn't have a reputation to put the inline-image.

Answer (score 0):

The `RunDetails(run_instance).show()` method from the `azureml-widgets` package shows the progress of your job along with streaming the log files. The widget is asynchronous and provides updates until the training run finishes.

Since the output shown is specific to your Pipeline run, you can troubleshoot it further from the [logs from pipeline runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-debug-pipelines#get-logs-from-pipeline-runs), which can be found in either the Pipelines or Experiments section of the studio.